# Save a Matlab Property to a mat file

Tags: matlab, oop, serialization, save, mat-file

I have a class with a `struct` property called `myStruct`:

```
properties
   myStruct;
end
```

I would like to save the struct to a `.mat` file. I tried:

```
save -append registers.mat myStruct;
```

But it gives the error:

```
Variable 'myStruct' not found.
```

I have different functions for updating the `struct`, like:

```
    function configureChannel( obj, Channel )
       myStruct.Channel = Channel;
       save -append registers.mat myStruct;
    end  

    function updateConfiguration( obj, dataPath )
       myStruct.EN = 1;
       save -append registers.mat myStruct;
    end
```

These are all functions of the same class.

Comment: You have to prepend your class property with the class name.

Comment: You mean like this?  save -append registers.mat myClass.myStruct It does not work.

Comment: Try `save -append registers.mat obj.myStruct;`. If it doesn't work - put it in a temporary variable, then save the variable (`a = obj.myStruct; save ...`). Also, I'm pretty sure you are creating a new local variable when you do `myStruct.Channel = Channel;` You should do `obj.myStruct.Channel = Channel;` instead.

Comment: @Dev-iL ...why not put that in an answer? :)

Comment: @Dev-iL also, it's strange that MATLAB then doesn't save the temporary...the OP must be calling `save` in a method without such a temporary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the main problem in this code is how you access `myStruct` from your functions. Take a look at the following piece of code:

```
function configureChannel( obj, Channel )
  myStruct.Channel = Channel;
  ...
end
```

What you *intended* for it to do was to assign `Channel` into the `Channel` field of the current object's `myStruct`'s `Channel` property. What it *actually* does is equivalent to calling:

```
myStruct = struct('Channel', Channel);
```

That is, you create a new **local variable** in the current workspace/scope of `configureChannel`, **without actually updating** the property of the object, `obj`.

So the first correction you need to make is how you access `myStruct` in your [*setter*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html#brh953v-3_6):

```
obj.myStruct.Channel = Channel;
```

---

Next is the issue of saving.

When dumping a copy of an object's field to a file, I would expect [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to treat your arbitrary object as a `struct`, and so [`struct` saving conventions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_variables) should apply:

> `'-struct',structName`  |  Store the fields of the scalar structure specified by `structName` as individual variables in the file. For example, `save('filename.mat','-struct','S')` saves the scalar structure, `S`.

Thus, I would expect the following to work <sup><sub>disclaimer: I didn't test it</sub></sup>:

```
save('filename.mat','-struct','obj.myStruct');
```

Other alternatives in case the above fails:

```
save('filename.mat','obj.myStruct');            % Alternative #1
tmp = obj.myStruct; save('filename.mat','tmp'); % Alternative #2
```

One last thing - as you may have noticed, I'm using the function form of `save`, because I consider it to be more maintainable/readable/fool-proof:

```
save(filename,variables,'-append');
```